# FindBin used, path still cannot be found

Tags: perl

I have a .pl file as follows :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw($RealBin); 
use lib "$RealBin/lib", "$RealBin";
use SDEBuild; 

$|=1;

my $obj = SDEBuild->new(LibDir=>"$RealBin/lib", LibDir1=>"$RealBin");
$obj->showGui(); 
exit 0;
```

The "SDEBuild" it uses is a .pm file, which `use`s `Moose` and has `LibDir` and `LibDir1` defined as follows :

```
has 'LibDir', is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1;
has 'LibDir1', is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1;
```

`LibDir` is `C:/path1/path2/lib` and `LibDir1` is `C:/path1/path2`.

`$self->LibDir/somefile` does locate C:/path1/path2/lib/somefile. However, `$self->LibDir1/somefile1` does *not* locate C:/path1/path2/somefile1. The error is "The system cannot find the path specified".

Any insights on this strange behavior?

Comment: `$self->LibDir/somefile` is a syntax error, so no idea how it can "locate C:/path1/path2/lib/somefile", whatever that means.

Comment: Oh, alright. My English isn't good. I suck at syntax *and* semantics, most probably. But I assumed one would get the drift. Perhaps you could help me out by giving me a hint as to what the error is. I'm a beginner - I (again) assumed that some help here would be an encouragement to learn better.

Comment: RealBin in this context is C:/path1/path2 - hence LibDir is C:/path1/path2/lib, yeah? And if the word "locate" I used was incorrect, I confess I was influenced by the documentation, which describes FindBin as "FindBin - *Locate* directory of original perl script"

Comment: Re "RealBin in this context is C:/path1/path2 - hence LibDir is C:/path1/path2/lib,", `$obj->LibDir` will return that, yes. `print $obj->LibDir, "\n";` would have told you that!

Comment: Re "And if the word "locate" I used was incorrect", If you read again, you'll notice I was pointing out you claimed that invalid code worked. I didn't ask what you meant by "locate".

Comment: As to why I need to *locate* it, I have to run a script toRun.pl (`system("perl $self->LibDir/toRun.pl");`)

And that wasn't a question, just a statement. As I said earlier, my English isn't good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says you successfully used the following:

```
$self->LibDir/somefile
```

That's obviously not true, since it's not valid Perl. A comment clarified that you actually used the following:

```
"$self->LibDir/somefile"
```

Well, that's obviously not true either. While it's valid Perl, it doesn't do what you want at all. Printing out the result gives something like the following:

```
SDEBuild=HASH(0xXXXXXXXX)->LibDir/somefile
```

There are limits to the expressions you can interpolate into a string literal. The following will work:

```
$self->LibDir . "/somefile"
```

Comment: Thank you. As was obvious, I wasn't sure what the syntax error was. I shall use this now. And, I'm grateful for your response - being a novice, a bit of encouragement goes a long way for me. Thanks again, sir!

Comment: Bewilderingly, the above seems to be a syntax error in my code - "String found where operator expected". To make things clearer, here's the exact line from my code :                                                                       `my $pid = open($fhOut, '-|', "perl $self->LibDir . /toRun.pl --option1 --option2");`

Comment: You put code in double quotes again . You recreated the very same problem my answer fixes. `"perl " . $self->LibDir . "/toRun.pl ..."`

Comment: Ah, now it penetrates my skull. I corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: Please note that `my $pid = open($fhOut, '-|', "perl $self->LibDir . /toRun.pl --option1 --option2");` does not gives `String found where operator expected` or any other syntax error. You've gotta stop saying stuff that isn't true!

Comment: Sir, you've helped me a great deal but I do resent being called a liar. I wonder what purpose you suppose I fulfill by "saying stuff that isn't true"? I *did* get the error I mentioned, and you did point out an error there : "You put code in double quotes again".

Comment: I didn't say you were a liar, and I don't believe you are. I believe you aren't careful enough. Be more attentive. You did NOT get that error from THAT code.